# Активный пункт меню

Tags: html, css

Сижу уже долго. Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно выровнить активный пункт мену, так, чтобы он выглядел так:

[image]
Так выглядит сейчас:

[image]

html:

```
<nav>
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">Сервис</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">Миномонтаж</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">Прайс-лист</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
nav {
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    background: url("../img/menu-bg.jpg");
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 100%;
}
nav a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
nav .active {
    background: url("../img/nav-active.png") repeat-x;
    height: 37px;
    width: 117px;
}
```

Comment: А напрячь булки, и попробовать самому решить, а что не понятно спросить. Что за мода просить сделать за Вас!?

Comment: Просто у меня заказ, и на долгие размышления нет времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть code inspector (я пользуясь в хроме) а в нем есть инструмент metric
P.S. Попробуй так:

```
nav div a { color: #000; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px; }
nav div ul { list-style: none; display: block; }
nav div ul li { float: left; margin-top: 12px; margin-left: 60px; display: block; }
nav div ul li.active { background: url(../img/nav-active.png) repeat-x; width: 117px; height: 37px; }
```

Comment: Спасибо!Но у меня не получается выровнять. Как сделать на active это  знаю. Но как сделать ровно так, как на первом скриншоте я не знаю.

Answer (score 4):

Так устроет! http://jsfiddle.net/yjAVq/

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы мне действительно помогли!